# ggplot2 - Assign symbol fill based on factors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, fill

I am relatively new to R and new to ggplot. I have a large data set and would like to make plots where the symbol fill for any given data series on the plot is governed by a factor in the data set. An example data frame is shown below where both "Station" and "Flag" are factors

```
Day Station Value Flag
1       1   0.0    b
2       1   1.0    a
3       1   2.0    a
1       2   2.3    a
2       2   1.0    a
3       2   0.2    b
1       3   0.5    b
2       3   0.5    b
3       3   0.5    b
```

I can control symbol shape and color using the factor "Station" but also want to control symbol fill using the factor "Flag" where, for example, filled symbols are used for Flag = "a" and open symbols are used for Flag = "b" - any given station will have a mix of filled and open symbols.  I can do this in the base plotting functions of R but can't get it to work in ggplot2. This would be very tedious to do for the real data set with many more stations or other factors of interest.

As I am new, the system won't let me post images (not enough reputation points) but here is the code I use to generate the figure I am looking for and the failed ggplot attempt - not shown are the numerous variations on "scale_fill_manual" that have not worked.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.table("dfquestion.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = "",
                  colClasses = c("Day" = "numeric",
                                 "Station" = "factor",
                                 "Value" = "numeric",
                                 "Flag" = "factor"
                                 )
                  )
##---------------------------------------------------
# Select parameter to graph
x.value <- "Day"
y.value <- "Value"
##---------------------------------------------------
# Subset data by Station
##---------------------------------------------------
Sta1 <- subset(data, Station == "1")
Sta2 <- subset(data, Station == "2")
Sta3 <- subset(data, Station == "3")
##---------------------------------------------------
#
# Set symbol colors and background. 
# open symbols/ clear background = value below reporting limit
# Black = Station 1
# Red = Station 2
# Green = Station 3
#
##---------------------------------------------------
bg.list1 <- rep(0,length(Sta1$Flag))
bg.list1[Sta1$Flag == "a"] <- "black"
bg.list1[Sta1$Flag == "b"] <- NA
#
bg.list2 <- rep(0,length(Sta2$Flag))
bg.list2[Sta2$Flag == "a"] <- "red"
bg.list2[Sta2$Flag == "b"] <- NA
#
bg.list3 <- rep(0,length(Sta3$Flag))
bg.list3[Sta3$Flag == "a"] <- "green"
bg.list3[Sta3$Flag == "b"] <- NA
##---------------------------------------------------
#
# Symbol type
# circle = Sta1; pch = 21
# square = Sta2; pch = 22
# triangle = Sta3; pch = 24
#
##---------------------------------------------------
opar <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
par(oma = c(0,1,0,2.5))
plot(Sta1$Day, Sta1$Value, type = "b", pch = 24, bg = c(bg.list1), cex = 1.2, col = "black",
     xlim = c(min(Sta1$Day), max(Sta1$Day)),
     ylim = c(range(na.omit(Sta1$Value),
                na.omit(Sta2$Value),
                na.omit(Sta3$Value)
                )),
 xlab = x.value,
 ylab = y.value,
 cex.lab = 1.25, cex.axis = 1.25,
 )
points(Sta2$Day, Sta2$Value, type = "b", pch = 21, bg = c(bg.list2), cex = 1.2, col = "red")
points(Sta3$Day, Sta3$Value, type = "b", pch = 22, bg = c(bg.list3), cex = 1.2, col = "green")
###
##---------------------------------------------------
# Creates legend outside primary graph
par(fig = c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma = c(0,0,0,0), mar = c(0,0,0,0), new = TRUE)
plot(0,0, type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")
legend("topright", legend = c(paste("Sta1"),
                     paste("Sta2"),
                     paste("Sta3"),
                     paste(""),
                     paste("above"),
                     paste("below")
                     ),
pch = c(21, 22, 24,
    NA,
    21, 21),
lty = c(NA), lwd = c(NA),
col = c("black", "red", "green",
    NA,
    "red", "red"),
pt.bg = c("black", "red", "green", 
      NA,
      "red", NA
      ),
text.col = "black",
bty = "n", cex = 0.95,
inset=c(-0.01,0.14))
#
par(opar)
#
##---------------------------------------------------
# Attempt to do the same thing in ggplot
#
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x=Day, y=Value, shape = Station, color = Station, fill = Flag)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) 
p <- p + scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22, 23)) 
p <- p + scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "green"))
# Adjust legend fills - filled = detect, open = non-detect
p <- p + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, fill = c("black", NA))))
print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `alpha` might be of use here.  I came up with a solution, but I'm not entirely happy with it.  I thought `alpha` would just impact `fill` for points that need both `color` and `fill` but it changed the transparency of both.  I ended up adding a second `geom_point` layer as a work around.

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x=Day, y=Value, shape = Station, fill = Station, color = Station)) + 
    geom_line(size = 1, show_guide = FALSE) + 
    geom_point(size = 4, aes(fill = NULL)) +
    geom_point(size = 4, aes(alpha = Flag)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22, 23)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "green")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "red", "green")) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0)) +
    guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, fill = c("black", NA), alpha = c(1,1))))
```

Comment: Yes! This seems to work. I had tried using `alpha` in various combinations but never got what I needed.  Many thanks.